# Find next unique element using next() for an iterable

Tags: java, iterator

I need to override iterator's `next()` function in my wrapper class so that each time I call `next()`, it will iterate through the `ScrollableResults`, add details, and ultimately return the unique record.

Because of how things are already set in place, each record with the same sequence number should be exactly the same *except* for the detail name and detail value. I need to add these details to the same record (that's what `record.addDetail(name, value)` does) and ultimately return that unique record. Here's a breakdown of what needs to happen for my custom `next()`:

1. Iterate through `scrollableResults`, adding detail name and detail value to the unique record (it can add to either unique ones).
2. Once the cursor comes across a different sequence number, it should break out of the loop and return the unique record/object.
3. Once returned, the next call to `next()` will start the process all over again except the cursor will pick up where it left off and `previousSequence` should also pick up where it left off.

**Wrapper.java:**

```
public class Wrapper<T> implements Iterable<T>, AutoCloseable {

    private ScrollableResults scrollableResults;
    private Session session;

    public Wrapper(ScrollableResults scrollableResults, Session session) {
        this.scrollableResults = scrollableResults;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() { return new WrapperIterator(); }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        scrollableResults.close();
    }

    public class WrapperIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private Integer previousSequence;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            boolean hasNext = scrollableResults.next();
            return hasNext;
        }

        /**
         * This next() method should return the next UNIQUE record.
         * But before returning the unique record, it should add all the appropriate details to the respective record.
         */
        @Override
        public T next() {
            boolean hasNext = scrollableResults.next();
            if (!hasNext) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            // For previousSequence, first result needs to be retrieved explicitly
            Object[] row = (Object[]) scrollableResults.get();
            Record record = (Record) row[0];
            Integer currentSequence = previousSequence = record.getSequence();
            String detailName = (String) row[1];
            String detailValue = (String) row[2];
            record = setDetails(record, detailName, detailValue);

            Object[] mainRow = row;

            // First one should always be unique since it's starting a new set of records of same sequence.
            while(scrollableResults.next()) {
                 // Get record
                row = (Object[]) scrollableResults.get();
                record = (Record) row[0];
                // Update current sequence
                currentSequence = record.getSequence();
                // If current sequence is different from previous sequence, break
                // First result needs to be accounted for
                if(!currentSequence.equals(previousSequence)) {
                    previousSequence = currentSequence;
                    session.evict(row);
                    return (T) row;
                }
                // Add detail
                detailName = (String) row[1];
                detailValue = (String) row[2];
                record = setDetails(record, detailName, detailValue);
            }
            previousSequence = currentSequence;
            return (T) mainRow;
        }

        private Record setDetails(Record record, String detailName, String detailValue) {
            record.addDetail(detailName, detailValue);
            return record;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to implement this and this is as far as I got. My current approach traverses and puts in details just fine but **my problem is in returning the right row. Since current sequence needs to be checked with the previous sequence, I can't return the very last record before the new sequence record since the cursor will be already past it.**

Any recommendation on how I could fix this? Anything would be greatly appreciated!

***NOTE:*** The iterator **CANNOT** traverse backwards. The scroll mode has been set to FORWARD_ONLY due to PSQL bug of the scroll mode needing to be FORWARD_ONLY.

Comment: What is the exact question/problem? (Have you noticed that you're calling `scrollableResults.next()` where you probably shouldn't?)

Comment: @ernest_k I updated it to be more clear about my question. I'm just unsure how to implement this.

Comment: I probably didn't fully understand what you're aiming at. But it sounds like this *might* be a case where "preparing" the next element should be a separate step. The pattern that is occasionally used here: 1. define a `private T next;`. 2. Implement `hasNext` as `next!=null`. 3. create a method `prepareNext` that will compute the next element to be returned. 4. In the constructor, do `this.next=prepareNext()`. 5. In `next`, do `T result=next; this.next=prepareNext(); return result;`. If you think that this can solve your issue, I'll try to convert this into an answer.